# Require nanotimer node_module in a service worker

Tags: javascript, node-modules, service-worker

In Electron, why would adding a require() in a service worker throw an `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`?

service.js

```
var NanoTimer = require('nanotimer');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think with Electron you can't use node in web workers (either normal workers or service workers).

See https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/797#issuecomment-62095954